# Is this PhpStorm warning about type hinting correct?

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

PHPStorm will warn me if I have method that type hints an argument as interface A, which I then pass as an argument to another method that type hints for interface B.

```
public function bar(InterfaceB $argument) {
}

public function foo(InterfaceA $argument) {
    bar($argument);
}
```

The call to `bar` will give me the warning 'expected parameter of type InterfaceA, InterfaceB provdied'.

At runtime, the objects I'm passing to `foo` implement both interfaces, so there is no problems.

Is PhpStorm warning me about code this is not best practice, or is the warning incorrect?

Also, this warning will not occur if the project only contains a single implementation of `InterfaceA`. But if there are two or more implementations of `InterfaceA` (both of which also implement InterfaceB), then I will get this warning.

Comment: How should PhpStorm know what the code is doing on runtime? If `foo` accepts both interfaces, why not use a proper type hint?

Comment: The warning is genuine. You type your parameter as `InterfaceA`, then you use it as argument for a parameter typed as `InterfaceB`. It works because the argument you pass to `foo` happens to implement both interfaces. But if that's the case, why not use `InterfaceB` as type for `foo`s argument. Or if you need to have both of them in some cases, create a third interface `InterfaceC` and make it extend A and B. Then use it as type for your parmeters.

Comment: @NoahBoegli I'm working within a framework (Magento 2), so I've massively simplified the problem. In reality bar is a framework method which typehints for a type, not an interface. Its particularly interesting that PHPStorm doesn't warn about this if there is only a single implementation of the interface, but two or more and you get the warning.

Comment: Also, if you remove the hint from foo, but leave it in bar, you don't get the warning. This makes sense as PHPStorm does not  know whether the argument implements InterfaceB or not. But then the same rational should apply when you type hint with InterfaceA; type hinting with InterfaceA doesn't preclude the argument also implementing InterfaceB